# How to Index (slicing) a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to implement k-nearest neighbor algorithm with the dataset which I have preprocessed. I imported the data as pandas dataframe and then converted it into numpy array but the following error is occuring-

```
      File "/home/user/Documents/Mooc_implementation.py", line 8, in <module>
  x = num_data[:,:10]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/records.py", line 499, in __getitem__
  obj = super(recarray, self).__getitem__(indx)
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

here is my code-

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd

    dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/student_reg_vle_info_assessment.csv')
    num_data = dataset.to_records(index=False)

    x = num_data[:,:10]
    y = num_data[:,10:11]

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)

    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
    print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

what should I do?

output of dataset.head()-

```
date_submitted  date_registration  date_unregistration  sum_click  \
0              18               -159                  445         16   
1              22                -53                  445          4   
2              30                -92                   12          3   
3              17                -52                  445          1   
4              26               -176                  445          5   

num_of_prev_attempts  age_band  region  highest_education  studied_credits  \
0                     0         0       0                  0              240   
1                     0         1       1                  0               60   
2                     0         1       2                  1               60   
3                     0         1       3                  1               60   
4                     0         2       4                  2               60   

score  final_result  
0     78             0  
1     70             0  
2     87             2  
3     72             0  
4     69             0  
[Finished in 0.274s]
```

Comment: can you add the data please ? also use `num_data.iloc`

Comment: after defining the num_data?

Comment: yes. use these: `num_data = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/student_reg_vle_info_assessment.csv')` then `x = num_data.iloc[:,:10]` and `y = num_data.iloc[:,10:11]`

Comment: yes its working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Q*: Why do you get this error?**

***A*: When you have a pandas dataset and you need to index it then you need to use .iloc method. The way that you indexing the dataset in your question works fine for numpy arrays indexing.**

---

***Use this:***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/student_reg_vle_info_assessment.csv')

x = dataset.iloc[:,:10]
y = dataset.iloc[:,10:11]
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case why are you doing `dataset.to_records(index=False)` it will convert to array and you can not use it like `num_data[:,:10]`. and also there no need to convert `dataset.to_records(index=False)` for train_test_split.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

num_data = pd.read_csv('/home/user/Documents/MOOC dataset cleaned/student_reg_vle_info_assessment.csv')
# num_data = dataset.to_records(index=False)

x = num_data.iloc[:,:10]
y = num_data.iloc[:,10:11]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: when I am doing that this error is occurring- TypeError: unhashable type

Comment: i have updated the answer, i forgot to write `num_data.iloc`